# Link between Harris recurrence and Ergodicity

Tags: ergodic-theory

Is it possible to obtain Harris recurrent Markov chain from Ergodic chain (in Birkhoff sense) under certain assumption? That is, suppose we know a Markov chain is ergodic (in Birkhoff sense); is it possible to make it Harris recurrent under certain assumption?

Answer (score 1):

No - because the definition of Harris recurrence contains an absolute continuity condition on transition probabilities. For an extreme counterexample just take any ergodic measure preserving transformation and consider it as a deterministic Markov chain.

Comment: If we restrict the ergodic chain, for example with compact state space, then is it possible to make it Harris recurrent?

Comment: No! - see above